# Taking g to be negative - where did I go wrong?

Tags: proof-verification, physics, classical-mechanics

Here's a problem I was doing.

> A ball bearing, $A$ of mass $450g$ is thrown vertically down with a speed of $4{ms}^{-1}$ from a height of $2m$. It bounces back and just reaches it's original height. Find the coefficient of restitution between $A$ and the ground. Take $g$ to be $10{ms}^{-2}$.

Here is my working out:

Taking down to be positive.
Finding the speed of approach:

$v^{2} = 4^{2} + 2(10)(2)$

$v^{2} = 56$ so $v = \sqrt{56}$

Then, to find speed of separation,

$ 0 = u^{2} +2(-10)(-2)$

But there's the problem. I won't be able to get $u$ on its own because I can't square root a negative number. I used $g = -10{ms}^{-2}$ here because now the ball is moving up (against down, which is +ve), and displacement is $-2m$ since the ball is moving up as well. But if I make one of them positive, I get speed of separation  = $\sqrt{40}$ and so I can calculate the correct value of $e$.

Comment: If $g$ is $10ms^{-2}$ and you take down to be positive then you should have positive 10 in the bottom equation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of *g* is independent of the direction the ball is moving. If you took the downward direction to be positive, then *g* should be used with a positive sign in your equation. This is why you got a negative value for $u^2$.